# Low Quality Posts Review Queue Response is "Delete" instead of "Recommend Deletion"

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I was reviewing in the [Low Quality Posts Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) and as I was reviewing, I saw a post that I wanted to see what other people thought about. I went back to that post, and I saw this picture.

> [image]

For me and the [desertnaut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4685471/desertnaut), it said "Recommend Deletion". However, for [Eric Leschinski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445131/eric-leschinski), it simply said "Delete". Why is that?

I checked his profile, and he has 89k reputation. Does that have anything to do with this?

Comment: You can click “Recommend Deletion” or you can cast a “Delete” vote (with sufficient rep).

Comment: ... and also with sufficient delete votes, else button turns back to "Recommend Deletion" even for 20k+ users

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At [20000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), you gain the ability to cast delete votes on negatively-scoring answers. At this point, the "recommend deletion" button turns into the "delete" button and actually casts a delete vote on the answer (a zero score also turns the button into "delete").

In this example, the user who chose "delete" was a trusted user, while the other 2 users didn't have 20000 reputation.

This information is also mentioned in the "Low Quality Posts" section of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work/161391#161391).

Comment: Just a minor correction here but delete votes can be cast manually only if the score is < 0 but a delete vote can be cast in the LQP queue if the answer is <= 0, above that >20k users have the option to Recommend Deletion.

Comment: ... which avoids to manually navigate & downvote to be able to delete.

Answer (score 8):

At 20K [you're a trusted user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) and thereby get the ability to delete answers.

At that point, provided you have delete votes available and the post qualifies, they are applied in the Low Quality Posts Review Queue.

With 2 or fewer Delete votes they are simply treated as Recommended Deletion. If a post accumulates 3 Delete votes, on its way to the necessary 6 Recommend Deletions however, it will be deleted by those Delete votes. I.e. deletion may happen with fewer reviewers involved.